# Activate M1 MBP without contacting Apple servers

Tags: install, apple-silicon, monterey, activation-lock

I'd like to have an airgapped M1 macbook, with some form of backup/disk cloning in case of hardware failures. Is there a way I can completely wipe/restore an M1 MacBook Pro without an internet connection?

- disk cloning seems very hard, since [several "hidden" partitions don't get cloned](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/05/28/why-cloning-big-sur-isnt-as-useful-for-an-m1-mac/)
- in fact, the internal SSD seems to be an integral part of the boot process (based on the above post); it's soldered-on anyway, so if it fails, it sounds like the whole macbook needs to get replaced

So without disk cloning, I think I'm stuck with hitting Apple servers to activate the macbook after an OS/disk wipe.

- there's some existing investigation into [caching the activation info for the touch bar](https://blog.eriknicolasgomez.com/2016/11/30/the-untouchables-pt-2-offline-touchbar-activation-with-a-purged-disk/), which might potentially still apply to M1
- Apple Configurator 2 also permits IPSW restores and a DFU mode, which includes T2 (possibly M1) firmware. But that seems to need a connection to Apple servers.
- some versions of T2 sound jailbreak-able, which might lead to some way to activate offline, but I don't believe M1 has the same vulnerability.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running an M1 Mac, the only way to use that device after a wipe is by first connecting it to the internet to Activate it.

Conceivably these are the two closest methods to achieving what you are after:

Either wipe a Mac, DFU restore it using the latest IPSW available (this process will talk back to Apple's servers), Activate it (also talks to Apple's servers), then run through the Setup Assistant bypassing the network selection (this will not work if it is a company owned device and assigned to an Apple Business/School Manager account)

Alternatively, purchase a brand new M1 Mac, hope it is on the desired operating system version, and then proceed through the Setup Assistant without connecting it to a network.

For any modern Mac, every method of upgrading or erasing/reinstalling the operating system will require at some point, connecting the device to the internet so that it can verify things with Apple's servers.

Comment: Ah, "For any modern Mac" makes me think that I could [run OpenCore on an actual Mac](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Post-Install/universal/security/applesecureboot.html#what-is-apple-secure-boot) to mock a T2, but this is definitely pushing the bounds of "worth the time to do". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After reading through [Eclectic Light posts](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/25/big-surs-signed-system-volume-added-security-protection/) + comparing setup methods on Intel + Apple silicon, the reason for connecting to Apple servers is due to what Apple calls "personalization", where the signatures of SSV partition files are checked with Apple. (It seems like the personalization servers will decline to verify any but the the latest releases of macOS, but that doesn't change the need to contact the servers.)

So, the only ways to install a SSV [[1](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc6/cloning-macos-system-volumes-apple-software-restore)] are 1) through the macOS installer, and 2) using the `asr` command line tool (macOS 11.1's `asr` seems to be broken, so this is only true in 11.2 or 12+). `asr` is Apple-proprietary, and mostly supports copying images to/from existing SSV's (which seem to be architecture-specific).

- This means I can back up a recent Mac + its System volume to an external drive, and also restore it offline, but
- **updating** requires you to run the macOS installer *somewhere*, which will then try to hit the personalization servers.
- And restoring across architectures (Intel => Apple silicon) just doesn't have the right SSV, so you'll need to find a matching SSV/backup, or run the macOS installer again.
  *Firmware updates are also excluded* from this process, so you'll be forced to run the macOS installer in those cases.

There *are* ways to construct a custom macOS image (manually `bless`-ing your modified System volume), but they require [disabling SIP + SSV](https://gist.github.com/macshome/15f995a4e849acd75caf14f2e50e7e98) (which is what OCLP does), which can be unacceptable depending on your threat model.
(Note that since SSV works with volume snapshots, you can always [roll back your SSV to the Apple-signed version](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/words-of-caution-regarding-modification-of-system-files-using-csrutil-authenticated-root-disable.2276764/), so this feels like less of a concern.)

---

For future reference, here's how I constructed a completely offline backup + restore for an Intel Mac (2019 MBP (with T2 chip), macOS Sonoma 14.2.1):

```sh
# first, reboot into macOS recovery (probably not necessary, but it's where I got things to work)

# manually create a r/w disk image to hold the... image
hdiutil create -fs apfs -size 80g -type sparsebundle -attach test4

# look for the `/Macintosh HD` disk in `diskutil list`: disk5s2
diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk5s2
diskutil apfs listSnapshots /dev/disk5s2

asr --source /dev/disk5 --target /dev/disk7 -toSnapshot AAAAA-GUID
```

The `-toSnapshot` is important, as it selects the SSV snapshot that gets preserved. This leaves you with a disk image that we can turn into a restoreable backup.

And to restore:

```sh
# Note that `asr` will re-order data on the source disk,
# so if you converted to a read-only image, you'll need to `hdiutil -shadow` to make it writeable.
hdiutil convert -format UDRO -o test4-singlefile test4.sparsebundle

# `asr imagescan` seems to pre-compute this re-ordering, but I haven't re-run this process to reconfirm
#
# Note that you can also use `FULL_USAGE=1 asr` to get more detailed asr usages,
# https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/asrs-hidden-documentation/
#
asr imagescan --source test4-singlefile.dmg --filechecksum --verbose

hdiutil mount test4-singlefile.dmg -noverify -shadow test4-shadow
asr restore --source /dev/disk8 --target /dev/disk4 --toSnapshot AAAAA-GUID --noverify
```

Notes:

- `asr` works on entire APFS Containers, individual volumes cannot be split out (`man asr` talks about the necessity of the Preboot and Recovery partitions)
- I left off all the image verification steps because they take a long time + I was running these commands many times (`-noverify` and `--noverify`).
- This whole thing is simpler with an external drive, but I'm using files for thoroughness.